# Can't enable panels in page-node

Tags: views, nodes, panels, i18n-l10n

Hello I'm building a multilingual (en/el) website using views panels taxonomy etc etc and other modules.All was fine with the world when suddenly I decided to customize the page-node by adding a panel layout which I created. The problem is that even when I saved the panel layout and the content on /node/%node nothing happened when I view an article. The article page ?q=node/3 for example remains unchanged.

I'm trying 2 says to find the solution but no luck at all.
Any info will be greatly appreciated, thnx in advance.

Comment: Do you add a "selection rules" with the node type?

Comment: Yes I did content type article. The content i added is of type article with a taxonomy tag.

Comment: I suppose you have cleared the cache. Have you added some pane in the panel?

Comment: Yep I cleared the cache many times and I did add content in the panel :) this is so weird...

Comment: you can check it out if you like and let me know if anything pops in your mind http://www.evented.gr/endeavor

Answer (score 0):

I recreated the website and added multilingual modules at the end. Now it works fine... still though I have no idea what was wrong...